# How to get CC.net build status for a project programatically?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

From a shell script, I want to detect if CC.net is currently building a project.  I have the URL of the CC.net server and the name of the project.

Heck, to make it easier, I'm running this on the CC.net server itself!  So any kind of local-process querying is fine.

I know I can grab the status page as HTML, and then grep that or something, but it seems awkward (especially as this is Windows).  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't mind writing some code you should be able to write a wrapper around ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.dll if you poke around the source for CCTray you'll see that it is calling ICruiseManager.GetProjectStatus() which will give you a ProjectStatus array containing each of the active projects, from there you should have all you need.